# How much performance difference does having variable values with powers of two make?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

Or is the difference insignificant for modern CPUs, including mobile? Let's say you have a million variables or so.

Comment: That very much depends on your code. It is very well possible that the JIT removes much of what you think.

Comment: Please clarify: are you asking if you should precompute the power values and store them in a list; vs. "always" computing them?

Comment: @Jägermeister - I think he is asking whether doing any math operation on  the number`8` would be faster than doing the same operation on `9`. It is rather difficult to tell and might vary from operation to operation. machines don't operate on *per-bit* basis. They operate on *per register* basis. So 2 int addition operations will take the same time *irrespective* of whether they are *power of 2 or not*. Its all about turning transistors on/off. Like Others have mentioned, the JIT might *optimize* your code in case one of the operands is of power 2 and you are doing multiplcation or division

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably makes no difference.

On typical processors, the arithmetic instructions take the same time irrespective of the values ... modulo hardware exceptions.  (They can take different times if the *types* are different, but that is a different matter.)

The only scenario where it is plausible for a power-of-two value to be faster is when the value in question is a constant and you are doing an integer multiplication or division.  In that case, it is *plausible* the the JIT compiler might turn the multiply or divide operation into a shift operation.  However, that is only going to happen for a (JIT) compile-time constant.

(Whether the JIT actually does this depends on the relative instruction times, and the sophistication of the JIT's optimizer.)